# Mute/unmute only a specific program

Tags: autohotkey

`m::Send {Volume_Mute}` is for the Master Volume... I need code only for mute/unmuting specific program...

```
IfWinExist ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
{
m::Send {Volume_Mute} 
}
```

won't work...

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way to mute a specific program with AHK is to download [Nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html), copy to the windows directory (it has a button when you run the exe)  and adapt the following

```
WinGet, WinProcessName, ProcessName, A
run nircmd muteappvolume %WinProcessName% 2
```

Comment: Or, if you know the .exe name: `Run, "Lib\nircmd.exe" muteappvolume "myprogram.exe" 2` to toggle mute/unmute

Answer (score 0):

You need #IfWinExist the # is very important - there is a big differences between IfWinExist with and without the **#** you can read more about it here https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm

Comment: This may fix an error in the code that OP posted, however even with that code working, it won't actually do what the OP is trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

For this answer, I'm assuming that you're using Windows Vista or later, as I'm not currently aware of a solution for Windows XP or earlier.

I haven't had time to try this yet, but you should be able to do what you want (mute a single program without muting everything else) using the [Vista Audio Control Functions](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/21984-vista-audio-control-functions/), by Lexikos.

I'll edit my answer to include more details when I have a little more time.